# Data set for Mcdonalds

Tags: data-request, data.gov, releasing-data, uses-of-open-data

Searching for any dataset on McDonald's Corporation; it doesn't necessarily have to be recent data. Any data on sales, employee, how they did during promotions, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this will be of interest to you, but some of the datasets related to McDonald's on Quandl include the following:

- News Sentiment History for McDondald's corp: https://www.quandl.com/data/NS1?keyword=mcdonald
- Open, High, Low, Close and Volume for McDonald's stock: https://www.quandl.com/data/GOOG?keyword=mcdonald

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]

Answer (score 2):

Statista has a number of datasets about McDonald's, you can cherry pick through here:

[Statistics and facts on McDonald's](http://www.statista.com/topics/1444/mcdonalds/)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get data on a company is to go to the "source," that is the company itself. The company's annual 10-K and quarterly 10-Q reports, filed with the SEC and posted on the company's website will give you quarterly data on sales, profits, etc., and at least annual data on employees. Companies like Quandl (represented by another poster) may give you more detailed data, but this is a good place to start.